# Can we run the output of go build generated from ubuntu to windwos

Tags: ubuntu, go

I am new to `Go`, so correct me if, i am wrong. Since `Go` executable are statically linked. So, can i code in windows as well as build it on the same but at the time of deployment if i use `Linux (ubuntu)`. So, is it possible to do so or i am missing something here.

Comment: This is what I plan on finding out. But right now, Bash on Ubuntu on Windows is broke when running Windows in a VM (mine has no network connection), so I am unable test.  But technically, it should use the Linux compiled version yes.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible, but a bit more complex than what you describe. Regardless of statically compiling, the Go compiler can generate code from any platform to any platform.

For a quick guide on how to do it, see this article http://dave.cheney.net/2015/03/03/cross-compilation-just-got-a-whole-lot-better-in-go-1-5